# SELECT DISTINCT and count

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

the table looks like this:

```
tag | entryID
----+---------
foo | 1
foo | 2
bar | 3
```

And now i want to get all tags with its usage:

```
foo | 2
bar | 1
```

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
select tag, count(*)
from MyTable
group by tag
```

Comment: okay, i shouldn't have skipped the grouping-part in the tutorial..
thank you